# Avoid armature deformation after add Track to Constraint

Tags: armature, constraints, parent

actually I want to add multiple empty controlers for each bone in armature

[image]

actually I can do all Track To bone constraints but I get unwanted deformations

[image]

after checking, the problem is with the bones that have some kind of parent

[image]

Currently I have tried to change the pairing to another object, or modify the constraint parameters, but nothing works.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

I would appreciate that you guide me on the right way

thanks

Comment: Is it at all possible you have accidentally swapped knees, eg right thighbone tracks to left knee empty and vice versa.

Comment: @batFINGER  actually was the first thing I though. but no, all is corrrect